# Trying to write a Sharepoint Online list field value to console using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I am very new to SharePoint CSR and using the REST api with AJAX. This is actually my first attempt outside of my workplace, where I am failing miserably. All I want to do is write a value from a field in my list to console, just to prove to myself that I can.

I am hoping to get some help on the structure of RESTful AJAX calls inside SharePoint. I have been banging my head on this for about 4 hours now, "not literally," and I cannot find the problem.

I am receiving an "**Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**" error when I try to run this script in SharePoint Online script editor.

I am using jquery-3.0.0.min.js. I have ensured it is properly loaded in the network tab of dev tools, and using an alert.

I would be eternally grateful for any help this community can provide me. I hope to be a competent SharePoint developer someday, but that day is definitely not today.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var url="/_api/Web/Lists(guid'26274651-afba-440d-bb64-274984a51218')/Items(1)?$select=Title"

function getItems(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('data.d.results');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use a decent IDE, Visual Studio Code is free, it will catch all these errors for you

Comment: And for CSR everyone must use the fantastic WYSYWIG editor (Chrome Extension)[**►Cisar**](https://365csi.nl/cisar)

Comment: Noted. I will check those out today after work, and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is giving you a hint. It says that a `)` might be missing. If you count the opening `(` and the closing `)` you will notice that you have one more `(` than `)` (12 vs 11).

If you than take a closer look one can notice that the `ready(` is never closed.

At the end of the script (right before the `</script>`) you are missing a `);` to finish this method call.

Comment: Holy crap. Thank you so much. I have never been into scripting and had to pick it up to fill some holes where I work. I will never forget to count the ('s and )'s again. Thanks for helping me get better.

Comment: Hi @ChrisLee glad I could help. Please have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Sorry about that. I cannot vote it up yet since I am new to stackoverflow. After I have 15 posts it will show my vote. I thought I hit the checkmark this morning. Thanks again.